# ValueError when running cartopy example

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I've installed cartopy with `pip install cartopy matplotlib -U`
Now I'm trying to run a very simple cartopy example from the gallery:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import matplotlib

print('cartopy', cartopy.__version__)
print('matplotlib', matplotlib.__version__)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

but got the follow errors:

```
cartopy 0.20.2
matplotlib 3.5.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 9, in <module>
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1086, in axes
    return fig.add_subplot(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 772, in add_subplot
    ax = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **pkw)
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 34, in __init__
    self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, [0, 0, 1, 1], **kwargs)
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 413, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 459, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 632, in __init__
    self.cla()
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 607, in cla
    self._boundary()
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 1602, in _boundary
    trans_path = proj_to_data.transform_path(path)
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1608, in transform_path
    return self.transform_path_affine(self.transform_path_non_affine(path))
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 170, in transform_path_non_affine
    new_vertices = self.target_projection.quick_vertices_transform(
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 1362, in quick_vertices_transform
    return_value = super().quick_vertices_transform(vertices, src_crs)
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 1247, in quick_vertices_transform
    if (x.min() >= x_limits[0] and x.max() <= x_limits[1] and
  File "/home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 44, in _amin
    return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

Should I open an issue, or is there a way to fix my cartopy install?

Here are some details about the installation of cartopy:

```
(base) ulrich@ulrich-ThinkPad-T490s:~/trash/sandwich$ pip install cartopy matplotlib -U
Requirement already satisfied: cartopy in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.20.1)
Collecting cartopy
  Using cached Cartopy-0.20.2-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.5.1)
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.5.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cartopy) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyproj>=3.0.0 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cartopy) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: shapely>=1.6.4 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cartopy) (1.8.1.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyshp>=2.1 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cartopy) (2.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (4.31.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (9.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyproj>=3.0.0->cartopy) (2022.5.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/ulrich/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: matplotlib, cartopy
  Attempting uninstall: matplotlib
    Found existing installation: matplotlib 3.5.1
    Uninstalling matplotlib-3.5.1:
      Successfully uninstalled matplotlib-3.5.1
  Attempting uninstall: cartopy
    Found existing installation: Cartopy 0.20.1
    Uninstalling Cartopy-0.20.1:
      Successfully uninstalled Cartopy-0.20.1
Successfully installed cartopy-0.20.2 matplotlib-3.5.2
```

Comment: I can't replicate your issue with identical versions, also on Windows, but installed using Conda instead of wheels. Have you tried some other commands? Add for example `ax.set_global()` or a more manual way of adding the coastlines `ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)`. It could be related to downloading/storing the Natural Earth data.

Comment: Well actually the error is already in `ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())`
and for the commands you propose, I need to run this first one.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I think my anaconda was kind of broken as I just reinstalled it and now it works.